# import in python when two folders with same name

Tags: python, import

I have what it seems to be an unusual situation.

```
── folder1
     ├── run.py
     └── pgm.py

── folder2
      └── src
           ├── fileA.py
           └── fileB.py

── folder3
      └── src
           ├── file1.py
           └── file2.py
```

Folder1 is mine, folders 2 and 3 are in forked and I don't want to change it, and I'm not sure I can put the three of them in a over-Folder.

In run.py, I have:

```
    sys.path.append(path_folder2)
    from src.fileA import classA
```

That ClassA, call pgm.py thanks to:

```
     module = importlib.import_module('pgm')
```

And pgm tries to import file1.py in folder3.src which import himself only files of folder3. Adding folder3 to path raise an ImportError. I presume it's because python looks in the subfolder src of folder2, how can I force to look in folder3 ?

In fact I'd like to be in the folder2 environnment as if folder 3 doesn't exist and then in folder3 as if folder2 doesn't exist during the same execution. How can I do that ?

Note: 
I didn't wrote the **init.py** for readability but they are in my folders and subfolders
I tried to play with path, removing folder2 just before importing file1.py but no success.

Comment: what is that "an error" thing?

Comment: What the error saids??

Comment: sorry : ImportError: No module named file1

Comment: Why don't you add the `src` directories to the path? `src` sounds to me like they contain the python modules, not a `src` package.

Comment: by sys.path.append ? If I do so, fileA.py cannot import fileB.py just by import fileB any more.

Answer (score 1):

You can rename module on import, like this:

```
from src.fileA import classA as fileAclassA
from src.fileB import classA as fileBclassA
```